# How to show lots of value JTable selected rows into one JText Area

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want to make a function if more than one row is clicked will bring up the data in one JText Area. 
I try this

```
Private void jTable1MouseClicked(java. awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel() ;
int selectedRowIndex = jTable1.getSelectedRow;

jTextArea1.setText(model.getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, 0).toString() + "," + model.getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, 0).toString());
```

I tried this method but the results actually double value with same value.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by building a string based on each table row that is selected through the Table model. Below is a method that will return a String array of each table row selected. Each element of this returned string array contains a Pipe (|) delimited string containing all the column data for each selected row:

```
public static String[] getJTableSelectedRowsData(JTable theTable) {
    // Gets the data contained within all Selected Table Rows.
    // Each array element within the returned string array will
    // contain a Pipe delimited data string of each selected row.
    int[] selectedRows = theTable.getSelectedRows();
    String[] resultArray = new String[selectedRows.length];

    DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) theTable.getModel();
    int nCol = dtm.getColumnCount();

    for (int i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++) {
        String resultString = "";
        for (int j = 0; j < nCol; j++) {
            resultString += resultString.equals("") ? dtm.getValueAt(selectedRows[i], j).toString()
                    : "|" + dtm.getValueAt(selectedRows[i], j).toString();
        }
        resultArray[i] = resultString;
    }
    return resultArray;
}
```

Now take this string array and build a Single string to dump into the JTextArea. It might go something like this:

```
String[] selectedTableRecords = getJTableSelectedRowsData(jTable1); 
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String str : selectedTableRecords) {
    sb.append(str).append(System.lineSeparator());
} 

jTextArea1.setText(sb.toString());
```

This may not be exactly what you were looking for but it may give you an idea of how to achieve what you need.